# How can I keep the mathematical order in this function?

Tags: python, functional-programming

I have this function *which returns the wrong result*

```py
def calc(a): return lambda op: {
    '+': lambda b: calc(a+b),
    '-': lambda b: calc(a-b),
    '*': lambda b: calc(a*b),
    '/': lambda b: calc(a/b),
    '=': a}[op]

calc(1)('+')(2)('*')(10)('=') # 30 -> should be 21
```

**Does anyone have an idea how I can keep the functional style and follow the correct mathematical order?**

Comment: If you're looking for currying, Haskell is basically built around this concept, while Python doesn't have it at all. You can probably implement it yourself, but it's not worth the pain, IMO

Comment: It doesnt have to be currying - but just a pure functional approach without assigning any variables or using statements.

Comment: `add(1, mul(2, 10))`. Don't try to mirror infix notation in your expression. (`add` and `mul` are predefined in the `operator` module, along with functions for the other operators as well.)

Comment: Python isn't a functional language. You _can_ write somewhat functional code with `lambda` functions and `map` and `reduce`, but that's almost it. If you want a purely functional approach, you're looking for Haskell. I think there are other purely functional languages, but Python isn't one of them. Again, you _can_ emulate functional style in Python, but that's like using a fork to eat soup - not terribly effective or productive.

Comment: @ForceBru Does currying do the correct operator precedences automatically?

Comment: Even in Haskell, you wouldn't try to combine the conversion of infix to prefix and evaluation in a single step.

Comment: @KellyBundy, I'm not sure whether currying has much to do with operator precedence. AFAIK, operator precedence is done during parsing, but currying is done at runtime. If you call curried functions in the correct order, you'll get correct operator precedence.

Comment: @chepner one shouldn't do this in practice but it is still a fun exercise..

Comment: Since `a` can also be a subexpression you could simply write `calc(1)('+')(calc(2)('*')(10)('='))('=')`. Otherwise you'd need to assign a precedence to each operator and accumulate all operators passed to `calc` (prior to their evaluation) to bring them in the order determined by precedence. Also you'd have to introduce parenthesis as a composite operator. This is may be too much work for a fun project..

Comment: [eval :-P](https://tio.run/##NYtNCsMgGET3OcVAF5@2FPKzKYK9i0ZDAjaKMYEiObuVlq7eDG8mvNPs1@ERYinGThiVG5niAtGmPa5w6qWNgg8C9lCuKixTrZASJAnWbfY/0uJ3nyirM/twZn0Sb5oQlzWxr@o4oxtx1ldeK7u2Bkmc44Khxf2Jbfa7M9AWfVfKBw)

Comment: @KellyBundy haha thats a funny one.

Comment: @IvenMarquardt I will wait with parenthesis - I was thinking that you only need to check the next operator to decide if the number should bind to left or right.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that I lack a firm understanding of Python hence the answer is going to be in JS. Hope it's still helpfull.

A proper solution needs to cover the following properties:

- operator precedence
- operator associativity (left/right/none)
- operator arity (unary/binary)
- round parenthesis

Operator associativity must not be confused with the mathematical property. An operator must either be left, right or not associative at all. The latter means the operator is not composable.

Precedence determines the evaluation order in case of different operators, associative in case of the same.

```
a + b - c = a + (b - c) :: - exceeds precedence of +
a - b - c = (a - b) - c :: - is left associative
```

This solution is just a rough sketch. It doesn't use string symbols as operators, which can be easily changed though. More importently it takes neither operator associativity nor parenthesis into account but always assumes left associativity and binary operators. It's just a start to get a notion for the complexity to be expected:

```js
const prec = n => o => (o.prec = n, o);

const prec1 = prec(1);
const prec2 = prec(2);
const prec3 = prec(3);
const prec4 = prec(4);

const add = prec1(x => prec1(y => x + y));
const sub = prec2(x => prec2(y => x - y));
const mul = prec3(x => prec3(y => x * y));
const div = prec4(x => prec4(y => x / y));

const infix = x => f => infix_(f(x));

const infix_ = partialF => y => {
  const go = g => {
    if (partialF.prec >= g.prec)
      return infix_(g(partialF(y)));

    else {
      const partialG = g(y);
      return infix_(z => partialF(partialG(z)));
    }
  };

  Object.defineProperty(
  go,
  "run",
  {get() {return partialF(y)}}); // lazy property getter
  
  return go;
};

const r1 = infix(2) (mul) (3) (sub) (4) (add) (5) (div) (2); // 2*3-4+5/2 = 4.5
const r2 = infix(2) (add) (3) (sub) (4) (mul) (5) (div) (2); // 2+3-4*5/2 = -5

console.log(r1.run);
console.log(r2.run);
```